# In Gdb how to set conditional breakpoint to a function's 3rd line

Tags: gdb

How can I set a conditional breakpoint to a function's 3rd line in GDB?

I know I could give the file name + line number but this is not working for me.
I have to store the gdb commands as a script to repeat it later and I don't want to change the script every time the source file is changing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about defining your own command file for gdb and then just sourcing it during debug? That would help reduce a fair bit of typing. Try this:

Create a file, let's call it mydef and here's its contents:

```
define cmd
  b function-where-you-want-to-break
  r
  b +2
  c
end
```

Once you load the executable in gdb, type in `source mydef` in gdb prompt followed by `cmd`

Now you are into the 2nd line from where function began. :)
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 4):

### Conditional Breakpoints

---

Type in the following,
assuming You have to apply a breakpoint at the line inside the function

```
(gdb) break <function-name>
```

GDB will reply with as follows
Breakpoint **1** at 0xaddr: filename , linenumber.

Note the number of the breakpoint
( in this case it is **1** )

Enter the following command
( replace the breakpoint-number appropriately )

```
(gdb) condition 1 <condition>
```

During run-time you can skip (step-over) to the 3rd line using the **next** command twice

```
(gdb) next
(gdb) next
```

..and you are at the function’s 3rd line!!

**UPDATE:**

Additionally, to break when the variable changes value use this:

```
(gdb) watch variable==value
```

---

For more details please refer :
-  **[GDB:Conditional Breakpoints](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~gilpin/tutorial/#3.4)**
- **[Hacking into an executable using GDB](http://2600hertz.wordpress.com/2010/01/14/hacking-into-any-executable-using-gdb/)**

Comment: Thanks, the problem is that the condition is only valid in the third line since it uses the functions local variable.